# Highest or Lowest Occurrences?

Tags: code-golf, string

### Challenge:

**Inputs:**

- A string containing printable ASCII (excluding spaces, tabs and new-lines)
- A boolean *†*

**Output:**

The parts of the String are divided into four groups:

- Lowercase letters
- Uppercase letters
- Digits
- Other

Based on the boolean, we either output the highest occurrence of one (or multiple) of these four groups, or the lowest, replacing everything else with spaces.

**For example:**

Input: `"Just_A_Test!"`
It contains:
- 3 uppercase letters: `JAT`
- 6 lowercase letters: `ustest`
- 0 digits
- 3 other: `__!`

These would be the outputs for `true` or `false`:

```
true:   " ust    est "

// digits have the lowest occurrence (none), so everything is replaced with a space
false:  "            "
```

(Note: You are allowed to ignore trailing spaces, so the outputs can also be `" ust    est"` and `""` respectively.)

### Challenge rules:

- The input will never be empty or contain spaces, and will only consist of printable ASCII in the range `33-126` or `'!'` through `'~'`.
- You are allowed to take the input and/or outputs as character-array or list if you want to.
- *†* Any two consistent and distinct values for the boolean are allowed: `true`/`false`; `1`/`0`; `'H'`/`'L'`; `"highest"`/`"lowest"`; etc. Note that these distinct values should be used (somewhat) as a boolean! So it's not allowed to input two complete programs, one that gives the correct result for `true` and the other for `false`, and then having your actual code only be `<run input with parameter>`. [*Relevant new default loophole I've added, although it can still use a lot of finetuning regarding the definitions..*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14110/52210)
- If the occurrence of two or more groups is the same, we output all those occurrences.
- The necessary trailing spaces are optional, and a single trailing new-line is optional as well. Necessary leading spaces are mandatory. And any other leading spaces or new-lines aren't allowed.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

### Test cases:

```
Inputs:                              Output:

"Just_A_Test!", true                 " ust    est "     (or " ust    est")
"Just_A_Test!", false                "            "     (or "")
"Aa1!Bb2@Cc3#Dd4$", either           "Aa1!Bb2@Cc3#Dd4$"
"H@$h!n9_!$_fun?", true              " @$ !  _!$_   ?"
"H@$h!n9_!$_fun?", false             "H     9        "  (or "H     9")
"A", true                            "A"
"A", false                           " "                (or "")
"H.ngm.n", true                      "  ngm n"
"H.ngm.n", false                     "       "          (or "")
"H.ngm4n", false                     "H.   4 "          (or "H.   4")
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to output the most/fewest as separate entries? For example, for the "hashing is fun" test case, can `"H           "` and `"     9      "` (with appropriate spaces) be output instead of `"H       9"`?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I don't get what you mean; both the `H` and `9` are part of the "fewest".

Comment: Can the boolean input value be `"max"`/`"min"`, which is then used as `Math[b]` to refer to `Math.max` or `Math.min`?

Comment: @JustinMariner You know.. I changed my mind sorry about that. I guess it's for JS? I think a lot of programming languages can utilize something like this, so too many of the existing answers should be changed. So sorry, you'll have to keep the `b?"max":"min"` in your answer.. It's a fine line I guess, maybe I should just use a truthy/falsey value next time..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>27</s> <s>26</s> <s>24</s> 22 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32014/zgarb)

-2 bytes thanks to [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393/leo)

Takes `' '` as `False` and `'a'` as `True` (In Husk, whitespace in Fasly and all other characters are Truthy)

```
Fż▲→ġ#¬Ö#≡⁰Ṫḟë½D±o¬□m;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9odXNr//9GxbzilrLihpLEoSPCrMOWI@KJoeKBsOG5quG4n8Orwr1EwrFvwqzilqFtO////ycgJ/8iSC5uZ200biI)

#### How does it work?

```
Fż▲→ġ#¬Ö#≡⁰Ṫḟë½D±o¬□m;   Function, takes a character c and a string S as arguments
                    m;   Wrap each character in S into it's own string
             ë           List of four functions returning booleans:
              ½D±o¬      Lower case?,Upper case?,Digit?,Not alphanumeric?
           Ṫḟ            Outer product with find†
       Ö#≡⁰              Sort on how many characters have the same Truthyness as c
    ġ#¬                  Group strings with equal numbers of spaces
   →                     Take the last group
Fż▲                      Squash it all into one list
```

*†* `ḟ` is a function that takes a predicate `p` and a list `L` and returns the first element of `L` that satisfies `p`. If no element satisfies `p` a default argument is returned. In this case `' '`. By applying `ḟ` to a one character string, we are essentially saying `if p c then c else ' '`.

`Ṫ` Is function that takes a function `f` and two lists `L1`,`L2`. It returns a table of `f` applied over all pairs of `L1` and `L2`. In this case `f` is `ḟ`, `L1` is our list of 4 functions, and `L2` is the list of one character strings.

After `Ṫḟ` we have a list of strings where each string is the result of replacing characters which don't satisfy one of the rules with a `' '`.

**NB:** In newer versions of Husk, `ġ#¬Ö#≡⁰` can be replaced by `k#≡⁰` for a 3 byte saving!

Comment: Out of curiosity: why `' '` and `'a'`? Maybe I understand it better when the explanation is added, because I can't read Husk. ;)

Comment: Nice! Here's [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9odXNr//9GxbzilrLihpLEoSPCrMOWI@KJoeKBsOG5qlNgPycgw6vCvUTCsW/CrOKWof///ydhJ/8iSC5uZ200biI) using `Ṫ`.

Comment: @Zgarb Thanks! I didn't really understand what `Mmm` was doing myself :)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really help with golfing, but `S\`?' ` might be simpler as `?IK' `

Comment: I tend to avoid using `I`, sometimes it makes the interpreter take forever. It also seems wasteful.

Comment: Wait, I've found [a shorter approach](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9odXNr//9GxbzilrLihpLEoSPCrMOWI@KJoeKBsOG5quG4n8Orwr1EwrFvwqzilqFtO////ycgJ/8iSC5uZ200biI "Husk – Try It Online") thanks to the fact that 'ḟ' returns a space when no element of a string satisfies its condition

Comment: @Leo Holy cow, this answer is getting short! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ØṖḟØBṭØBUs26¤f€³Lİ⁴¡$ÐṀFf
¹⁶Ç?€
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVYAqf9qZWxsef//w5jhuZbhuJ/DmELhua3DmEJVczI2wqRm4oKswrNMxLDigbTCoSTDkOG5gEZmCsK54oG2w4c/4oKs////IkhAJGghbjlfISRfZnVuPyL/Mg)**

The boolean values are `2` and `1` (or any other positive even/odd pair), which represent `True` and `False` respectively. I will try to add an explanation after further golfing.

Thanks to [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing) for saving 2 bytes, and to [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn) for saving 4 bytes! Thanks to one of [Erik's tricks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146736/59487), which inspired me to save 4 bytes!

### How it works

Note that this is the explanation for the 35-byte version. The new one does roughly the same (but tweaked a bit by Lynn), so I won't change it.

```
ØBUs26f€³µ³ḟØBW,µẎLİ⁴¡$ÐṀF - Niladic helper link.
ØB                         - String of base digits: '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
                             abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'. 
  U                        - Reverse.
   s26                     - Chop into sublists of length 26, preserving shorter
                             trailing substrings.
      f€³                  - For each, keep the common characters with the input.
            ØB             - Base digits.
          ³ḟ               - Get the signs in the input. Filter the characters of the
                             input that aren't alphanumeric.
              W,µẎ         - Concatenate (wrap, two element list, tighten).
                       ÐṀ  - Keep the elements with maximal link value.
                  L        - Length.
                    ⁴¡     - Do N times, where N is the second input.
                   İ       - Inverse. Computes 1 ÷ Length. 2 maps to the length itself,
                             because 1 ÷ (1 ÷ Length) = length; 1 yields
                             (1 ÷ Length), swapping the maximal numbers with minimal ones.
                         F - Flatten.

¹⁶e¢$?€ - Main link.
      € - For each character.
   e¢?  - If it is contained by the last link (called niladically), then:
¹       - Identity, the character itself, else:
 ⁶      - A space.
```

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjESdwzMcgdjl0NaHu/oObU5TedS05tDWQ5sf7ph/eIZTuA5EfKvPkQ2PGrccWnho6@EJD3c2uHEd2vmocVvqoUUq9kAN////V/IqLS6Jd4wPSS0uUVT6bwQA)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks! :) I wanted to golf that part ever since I posted the answer, but I couldn't figure out why it didn't work... I had an extraneous `µ` D:

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##AVYAqf9qZWxsef//w5jhuZbhuJ/DmELhua3DmEJVczI2wqRm4oKswrNMxLDigbTCoSTDkOG5gEZmCsK54oG2w4c/4oKs////IkhAJGghbjlfISRfZnVuPyL/MQ): generate the classes as `ØṖḟØBṭØBUs26¤`, and then test membership with `f` and `Ç` instead of `e¢$`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>166</s> 158 bytes

```python
t=lambda c:('@'<c<'[','`'<c<'{','/'<c<':',1-c.isalnum())
def f(s,b):x=map(sum,zip(*map(t,s)));print''.join([' ',c][x[t(c).index(1)]==sorted(x)[-b]]for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYxRT4MwFIXf9yvKJLm9pqth24s4IlNjzJ73RgiWUlwNFEJLgvrjUfFhM5q9ffc759z2zR0asxxHF1WizgtBZEghho3cQAIMnif6@KKriUJgwUJybUVl@poizgpVkpJalmM4RLVoqe1r9q5bevl9OGYR8abttHEA/LXRhiZAgMk0GRJHJXJtCjXQANMosk3nVEEHTBZ5mpZNRyTRhlgcSzrf9dZl22yvrPPmjOy7XuHsr38Ulf0JtiLw7vJlfC9XFw/F2j8dPcX@wTPXmednZW9uz0cnL38VuXmpuflfHTeTWx/d@Ak)

Comment: [158 bytes](https://tio.run/##fYxRT4MwFIXf9yvKJLm9pqth24s4IlNjzJ73RgiWUlwNFEJLgvrjUfFhM5q9ffc759z2zR0asxxHF1WizgtBZEghho3cQAIMnif6@KKriUJgwUJybUVl@poizgpVkpJalmM4RLVoqe1r9q5bevl9OGYR8abttHEA/LXRhiZAgMk0GRJHJXJtCjXQANMosk3nVEEHTBZ5mpZNRyTRhlgcSzrf9dZl22yvrPPmjOy7XuHsr38Ulf0JtiLw7vJlfC9XFw/F2j8dPcX@wTPXmednZW9uz0cnL38VuXmpuflfHTeTWx/d@Ak_)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks; Just got that as well  :)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>193</s> <s>186</s> <s>179</s> 158 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to NofP and his suggestion of `cbind`*

*-6 bytes using `outer`, -1 byte switching `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` with `[[:punct:]]`*

*-21 bytes thanks to MickyT for pointing out a list of characters is allowed*

```r
function(S,B){y=outer(c("[a-z]","[A-Z]","\\d","[[:punct:]]"),S,Vectorize(grepl))
S[!colSums(y[(s=rowSums(y))=="if"(B,max,min)(s),,drop=F])]=" "
cat(S,sep='')}
```

[Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##tZDRSsMwFIbv@xRrHCyBdGy6m40F7RQd3la8sKslS7OukCYhSdFO9uw1VRFRwSsJh5z/gyTfielEtTXUtLDmbq8Ki4LdYBl1u0YyVykJE7xCLy1RjeMGMghSGh0ygEEaRw/9vtkUfUoXuj@xyDKAcILvOXPKVAcOS8O1QChI0pApkTS1hW0KLTHq6T0gRAiodgCucE2fcV1JBC3CuDBKk@sMZQQMQMCo8yqWazIaoWNXLqNPw5veMCFcQOuM1aJyHgHg3/xb@9FjTybR/J@8NbWOe3N/h6Da8jf9oKZaixaW2JvdNtblcX7HrQu90rcY02m42p7Gl@zs5KqYDT1aXwz3oZzn4TD3f3D@K4k/aj2WZT2WP7uZ9PMyOMUTv6ZfaoJQ9wo)

Takes `1/T` as truthy (`max`) and `0/F` as falsey (`min`), and takes `S` as a list of single characters.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY49T8MwEED3/IpyS@@kCwKJqcIDHRB7JAZcD8FxWkvxh86OIEX89tCI6ekNT3qyTv5TelkwuHpJQ6Fm3D236zhHW32K2PGRfhaV5uoELYLu26sBBv3Sfmw8nYbN9CFvxcEYIO743dmaxF8dnsXliajp9J1NUzeHgovGoiR9/QuRUuBHwCOH/puDj4SFmAdJWb0aMgp20Ni@3laKy2q/p991xFKl5MlXhLf7eA5P8XYBpPWjMfxA6x8)

In my original version (with NofP's suggestions), the matrix `y` is constructed by evaluating `grepl(regex, S)` for each `regex`, then concatenating them together as columns of a matrix. This results in multiple calls to `grepl`, but as `S` is fixed, it seemed that something else needed to be done. As I noted:

> There are potentially shorter approaches; `mapply`, for example:
>
> `y=mapply(grepl,c("[a-z]","[A-Z]","\\d","[^a-zA-Z0-9]"),list(S))`
>
> unfortunately, this will not simplify as a matrix in the 1-character example of `"A"`.

I used `outer` rather than `mapply`, which *always* returns an array (a matrix in this case), and was forced to `Vectorize` `grepl`, which is really just an `mapply` wrapper around it.

I also discovered the predefined character group `[:punct:]` which matches punctuation (non-space, non-alphanumeric) characters.

Comment: If you replace the matrix with a cbind, you could reduce to 186 bytes:

y=cbind(g("[a-z]",S),g("[A-Z]",S),g("\\d",S),g("[^a-zA-Z0-9]",S))

Comment: @NofP oh, very nice. Also, you can surround code with backticks (\`) to have it display `like this`. :)

Comment: The rules state that you can use a character array or list as input , so you could probably remove the `S=el(strsplit(G,""))`

Comment: @MickyT ah, I overlooked that, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>31 29</s> 28 bytes

```
SMS?' `ṁ§foSM≠?▲▼⁰M#Kë½D±o¬□
```

Uses 0 for minimal and 1 for maximal character counts.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUkAtv9odXNr//9TTVM/JyBg4bmBwqdmb1NN4omgP@KWsuKWvOKBsE0jS8Orwr1EwrFvwqzilqH///8x/yJIQCRoIW45XyEkX2Z1bj8i)

### Explanation

Lists of functions are cool.

```
SMS?' `ṁ§foSM≠?▲▼⁰M#Kë½D±o¬□  Inputs are bit B and string S.
                     ë        Make a list L of the four functions
                      ½       is-lowercase-letter,
                       D      is-uppercase-letter,
                        ±     is-digit, and
                         o¬□  not is-alphanumeric.
                  M#          For each of them, take number of matches in S,
              ?▲▼⁰            take maximum or minimum depending on B,
          oSM≠                and mark those entries that are not equal to it.
        §f          K         Remove from L the functions that correspond to marked entries, call the result L2.
                              These functions test whether a character should be replaced by a space.
SM                            Do this for each character C in S:
      `ṁ                      Apply each function in L2 to C and sum the results.
  S?'                         If the result is positive, return space, otherwise return C.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 140 bytes

```python
g=lambda x:x.isalnum()-~(x>'Z')*x.isalpha()
def f(s,m):k=map(g,s).count;print''.join([' ',c][k(g(c))==sorted(map(k,range(4)))[m]]for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1NT4NAFEX3/RVDJZn3munEVja2QVt1YVy7khAy5Vs6D8IMCW786xjFCEldvnPvua/5sEVN22HI/bPSp0SxftfL0qgzdRpw/Qn9HX/juBphUyjARZJmLAMjNO4qX6sGcmFQxnVHdt@0JVnO5XtdEgSccRGHQQU5xIi@b@rWpgl8O5VoFeUpeIgY6DDM6pbFrCRmcMhg@dIZGx2j19RYZynYeoOLS3r9A49q4zyctofH@ObqKfHcqf5PMirPB7dw6DZy3Cjr6H4yLoPfH7PRaUVSriXN7D8wK3jjPXwB)

Jonathan Frech saved a byte. Thanks!

Highest is `m=-1`, lowest is `m=0`.

Comment: I think you can save a byte by replacing `+x.isalpha()*-~(x>'Z')` with `-~(x>'Z')*x.isalpha()`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>448</s> <s>439</s> <s>432</s> <s>362</s> <s>361</s> <s>354</s> <s>352</s> <s>348</s> <s>343</s> 320 bytes

```java
s->b->{int w[]=new int[4],m=0,n=-1>>>1,l;s.chars().forEach(c->{if(c>96&c<123)w[0]++;else if(c>64&c<91)w[1]++;else if(c>47&c<58)w[2]++;else++w[3];});for(int W:w){m=W>m?W:m;n=W<n?W:n;}l=m-n;m=b?m:n;return l<1?s:s.replaceAll("["+(w[0]!=m?"a-z":"")+(w[1]!=m?"A-Z":"")+(w[2]!=m?"\\d]":"]")+(w[3]!=m?"|[^a-zA-Z0-9]":"")," ");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZLRbpswGIWvl6cwLJpggBUS1i1xIE27TtW0XXVSpFEWOcRJyGyDsClqM549M4V16rRKW@ECme/4Pz7yYY9vsJNmhO/X348Jy9Jcgr1isJAJhZuCxzJJOXyNelmxokkMYoqFAJ9xwsGhJySWin1ot02vZJ7wrf0bnKUpJZjboFGCAOyS7Y4I@Skt1Rv44CicYOUEh4RLUIaRz0kJ1Dr0Ipv5A5v7jhsEgWtTJGC8w7kwTLhJ8wsc74y4ntsYcTA@eRVP3eHILMNBZFmIUEHAvXLiKWXsKsF9LHhvlfDmnRKGvwTLKsNRhCoTqQOMOtBiUpoH5i8CNltMGOL@YsrViqOK@szhiPmrGVOfOZFFzgGdujMxETAnGcUxmVNq6KFuGXUqzWczHTt3@kTXzRq5DZo7Xx/QsEHX1@tIsaiBowb@CL@pabV74Iyj@wlbB7qJqiNqm2nLuEmTNWCqH6O58zAC2FRdvbi6FZIwmBYSZkqQlBuPyoA4y@itoV@e9ncaHy@1/lL1P9PNVpB5QUwT9UD7dPXbYHXnteE/J/tYCLmcL78opHWO9Vez/880x652thqensejl@/XXr9zricNn5Gte5gOp19CvmWQd/9//vB5SPIsI@8Jo6pXHX8C)

Comment: [366 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/y7zb8nvd)

Comment: You can remove the `+` in `\\|+$` for an additional -1 byte.

Comment: You can save three more bytes by changing the last part to `String r=(w[0]!=m?"[a-z]|":"")+(w[1]!=m?"[A-Z]|":"")+(w[2]!=m?"[0-9]|":"")+(w[3]!=m?"[^a-zA-Z0-9]|":"");return r.isEmpty()?s:s.replaceAll(r.replaceAll(".$","")," ");}`.

Comment: Oh, and `n=s.length()` can be `n=-1>>>1` for an additional -4.

Comment: Oh, one more small thing to golf: `[0-9]` -> `\\d`

Comment: Suggest `{0,0,0,0}` instead of `new int[4]` and `int z=c>96&c<123?w[0]++:c>64&c<91?w[1]++:c>47&c<58?w[2]++:++w[3];` instead of `if(c>96&c<123)w[0]++;else if(c>64&c<91)w[1]++;else if(c>47&c<58)w[2]++;else++w[3];`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 35 bytes

```
ØWṖs26µẎØṖḟW⁸;
¢ċ@€S¥€N⁹¡Mị¢Ẏ⁸f€ȯ€⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjPCHO6cVG5kd2vpwV9/hGUDOwx3zwx817rDmOrToSLfDo6Y1wYeWAkm/R407Dy30fbi7@9AioFKgijSg6In1QOJR47b///8reTioZCjmWcYrqsSnlebZK/03BAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>118</s> 116 bytes

Takes `0` (lowest) or `-1` (highest) for its second argument.

-2 bytes thanks to Lynn.

```ruby
->s,t{s.gsub(/./){|c|[/\d/,/[a-z]/,/[A-Z]/,/[^\da-z]/i].group_by{|x|s.scan(x).size}.sort[t][1].any?{|x|x=~c}?c:" "}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZLBboJAEIbvPMWAHLCBRawXmyDa9kB67qlICSyIJO1KWEhAoK@Ou5RWqnUus5n/m5l/s5sVQdXtiNlpK6rmNUUxLQJFR/q0bnDj6NtQV3XH144uzxvtrc/v27AvJS6Ks0ORekFVN2VDEcU@UcoposkxahE9ZLmTu47hIp9UFkdK8wu3Fn6QQGrbLiFpkYMJjgAgvRQ09zbea0RzUVKBh2awPAFzBRIwlZeYCtINfHamR9HTG98QH4P5@gnfT57Dhcw6RsOvVN5ir@W9SJaeKHu7glh8x9jPWgYRgKtsh3Wr42zJ7s0s/7oajA@Tf2NwdcHMrpHvMTYi8SciP3e6ZICpQC7I/4aNnPXg4gZoI3ZcMNAVhP4JUeTjvUc/Ehwpc/Zz/CymDaSwI84dP7vQdic)

### Ungolfed

```ruby
->s,t{
  s.gsub(/./) {|c|
    [ /\d/,
      /[a-z]/,
      /[A-Z]/,
      /[^\da-z]/i
    ]
    .group_by {|x| s.scan(x).size }
    .sort[t][1]
    .any? {|x| x =~ c } ? c : " "
  }
}
```

Comment: Very cool answer! You can use `-1` as the “highest” value and replace `minmax[t]` by `sort[t]`.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>190</s> <s>183</s> <s>174</s> 173 bytes

Thanks to Jonathan Frech for shortening it

```python
from re import*
def f(i,c):
 q='[a-z]','[A-Z]','\d','[\W_]';l=[len(set(finditer(p,i)))for p in q]
 for j,k in enumerate(l):
	if k-eval(c):i=compile(q[j]).sub(' ',i)
 print i
```

This takes the strings `'max(l)'` and `'min(l)'` as true and false. (I don't think this breaks the rules...?)
This is longer than the other two python answers but different so I thought I'd post it. I'm not a great golfer so I'm guessing this could be improved further but all the things I tried didn't work.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BS8QwEIXP9ldMYyGJtIKrF5XiVj2IZ0GwW0q3nbCzm6Zpmor652t7kUV0Lo@Px/fGfvpdZ1bTpFzXgkOg1nbOnwUNKlCC4lreBNCnPK@Sr4LHPM@StyU3zQKb17LgtzrNNRoxoBeKTEMenbAxSSlV58ACGeiLABbYx4cF0Ywtusqj0PP@CSk4JPheaTG/o7TuWksaRZ/vC3k@jFvBgc97AVhHxgNNSrCndbQLzXUZRqUazR2DGFhbfcyDTAb/9WR@@udx8GVWvuDgQwbz/fL/7I/8rLoI77er9UN9efrYXEXsyJ@@AQ)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! When I try to run this, I get errors, and I'm not entirely sure why. One reason could be that `sum(1for m...` should be `sum(1 for m...`, but I think there are other problems too. Could you provide a link to an online interpreter (such as [tio](https://tio.run/#python2)) to demonstrate how you're calling this, and to show it isn't erroring?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I just added a link, thanks for providing the link I wasn't sure how to do it. I am not getting an error when I run it there.

Comment: Ah, I couldn't tell that you were inputting `max(l)` and `min(l)` as strings, that's why I was getting errors. Thanks for clearing that up! Although now, this is on the edge of violating rule #3, ` Note that these distinct values should be used (somewhat) as a boolean`, but it's definitely a little bit of a gray area.

Comment: BTW, here's a TIO pro-tip: If you put your function calls in the *footer* field, they won't be counted towards your byte count, so you can easily see how long your answer is: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7RSsMwFIbv@xRpLSSBdrDpjZPiql6I14JgFkLXJuxsTZqmqagvX5sN2c2uzvn5@L9z7I/fd2Y1TaBt5zxyMmqkQopAVtN1hPqCYVblvxxnmJX5Z5jbJoTth@CYP7QFG0ZNlqpzSCMws2GhwDTgpSM2A0oDsYH0PEIhmBDY4bQfsmNI0oxauspL0lJQ6JjLr6olNeVrKGZh3WkLrSQ9M5wuhnFHMMKzO0LWgfEIJkXw6ybdx@ZexKlQo3mcf9TV9@zDNLpOwfzT5G0cvCjFuxx8nGTJuZhcRafWGZXVMn7arTbP9e3NS3OXJpeT0x8 "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Ah thanks. I agree it's kind of a gray area. I could take 'max' and 'min' as true false then do eval(c+'(l)') which adds 6 Bytes and seems more acceptable but until OP disallows my answer I'm assuming it's okay.

Comment: [183 bytes](https://tio.run/##dYzBSsQwFEXX7Ve8xkISaQVHN44Up@pCXAuCnVI6bcK8mSRN01TUn6/tRgbRt7nvcLjXfvp9Z1bTJF2nwQlAbTvnz8NWSJAMk4avw6DPaFGnXyVNaJGnb0tu2wW2r1VJb1VWKGGYwsEziaZFLxyzCXLOZefAAhroyzBYwMxQHGB5D8lxMcKMWrjaC6Y4Sjim4r1WrOHlGrOm0xaVYH1hSn4xjDtGgc7DYWAdGg84SUaeNvE@MjdVFFdyNHcEEiC6/pjnCA//82h@/PM4@CqvXsTgIwLz/er/6U/6eX0Z3e9Wm4fm6uyxvY7JSX/6Bg); in my opinion your boolean values are acceptable, as they are `two consistent and distinct values`.

Comment: [174 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY3BSsQwFEXX5iteYyGJtIKjG5XiVF2Ia0GwU0qnTZg3k6Zpmor68zXdyCD6No/D4d5rP/2uN6t5Vq7vwEnAzvbOn5FWKlAck0bcEBgyVtTpV8kSVuTp2/I37QKb16pktzortDRc4@i5QtOil47bBIUQqndgAQ0MJYEF9slhQWmmTrraS67DwAkqOKTyvdY87GHW9J1FLflQ7EtxPk5bzoCFPgLWofGAs@L0aR3vInNdRXGlJnNHIQHa1R@hkAryn0fz45@n0Vd59SJHH1EI9yv/pz/K5/VFdL9drR@ay9PH9iqmR/n5Gw).

Comment: Assuming that `finditer(...)` produces unique objects, one could save a byte by using `len(set(...` instead of `len(list(...`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Yeah `finditer` produces unique objects so `set` works over `list`. Thanks for all the edits!

Comment: @JonathanFrech `list(findall(...` would have also shortened it by one byte but `findall` just returns the matches as strings so `set(findall(...` doesn't count duplicates of characters in the input string.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>161</s> 158 bytes

```php
for([,$s,$z]=$argv;~$c=$s[$i++];)foreach([punct,upper,lower,digit]as$f)(ctype_.$f)($c)?$$i=$f:$g[$f]++;while(~$c=$s[$k++])echo$g[$$k]-($z?min:max)($g)?" ":$c;
```

Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e26f96f1adb2a7d5702c478480c8e5384ff2260c).

- first loop: for each position, remember the group of the character
  and count the occurences of groups that the current character is *not* in.
  (that negation saved 3 bytes)
- depending on second parameter, pick min non-count for truthy, max non-count for falsy.
- second loop: if (group of current character) non-count differs
  from min/max non-count then print space, else print character.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Make sure you have the latest PHP version (7.1.0) selected.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>151</s> 149 bytes

```js
g=
(s,f,a=[/\d/,/[A-Z]/,/[a-z]/,/[_\W]/],b=a.map(r=>s.split(r).length))=>s.replace(/./g,c=>b[a.findIndex(r=>r.test(c))]-Math[f?"max":"min"](...b)?' ':c)
```

```html
<input id=s oninput=o.textContent=g(s.value,f.checked)><input id=f type=checkbox onclick=o.textContent=g(s.value,f.checked)><pre id=o>
```

Sadly the rules probably don't allow me to pass `Math.max` or `Math.min` as the flag. Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @JustinMariner.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 37 bytes

```
ØWṖs26µẎØṖḟW⁸;
¢f@³L$ÐṂFe@Ð€³¬¹⁴?a³o⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AV0Aov9qZWxsef//w5hX4bmWczI2wrXhuo7DmOG5luG4n1figbg7CsKiZkDCs0wkw5DhuYJGZUDDkOKCrMKzwqzCueKBtD9hwrNv4oG2////SEAkaCFuOV8hJF9mdW4//zE)

-6 bytes "borrowing" from Erik's post :D

Comment: Lol preserving the spaces is essentially half the program :D

Comment: Could you add an explanation, or are you still working on golfing it first?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Golfing first :D

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <s>229</s> <s>227</s> 212 bytes

```
LANG=C;g="A-Z a-z 0-9 !A-Za-z0-9";declare -A H
f()(((i=$2?99:-1));r=$1;for h in $g;{ t=${r//[$h]};t=${#t};(($2?t<i:t>i))&&i=$t&&H=([$h]=1);((t-i))||H[$h]=1;};for h in $g;{((${H[$h]}))||r=${r//[$h]/ };};echo "$r")
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##ZY3Bb4IwGMXv/hVfscH2UBH1gl2nnUtGlmUnT1sWggiUZMOk1MuQv50VlZiF2/fe@7337eNKte2bfH8RW54LR7IPiNkvzFgAyAp729PhhzT5jnUKTEI4ygglhBQCz9dBsGI@pVwL7PPsqEFBUQLOeQ1G4Fp73idWXw3vxNg0nBBbMg/FyjwWlLquHTGuGwrSYcKnFjDMJudzeHV483/WDtSXqOkgff/hQWPZNFFHcLB2aJvB5PVUmUhGu7QyaAL@aGDNOkvGPnrazzfbZDF@PizxjRzaFzrcYIXKIEI4yk7l@gYP3OtyP9V3p2X@My37Tq/u2bJT7R8)

Comment: I'm not sure how the spaces around brackets and square-blocks work in Bash, but [it still seems to work without the space at `f(){((`](https://tio.run/##bY0/b4MwFMT3fIpHYhF7cAhpFuK6gaZSUVV16lSEECH8k1oiGWcp@LNTk4Ay0O1@9@7uHeO66Lp37@OVH1jOsUe/IKa/sKYOGBq01pKwU5p8xyIF6oE/yzBpAOOSo83ecXbUJoQJjmyWnQUUUFaAmjxwQ8UakBw1wrICVGjsYSEVw1g35WO5k08lIaapl6Rp@hz3Ma2JTkiqT23rDxZT/60HgYZrREEYtq24f7NA6U6aFGeYIzFnqstg@XapZeRFn2ktjSXYs4m17i0vto3n48Y9JA@Ll9MWDcmpfU37LiqMyokMFGWXaj@EJ@5teZwau6sq/1lVY2ek@23bU/cH).

Comment: yes, space is mandatory generally except for `(`, also 2 bytes could be saved using `(` instead of `{`, degrading performance because creating a subshell

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>307 + 34</s> <s>306 + 27</s> 295 bytes

My "interesting" take on the challenge.

Thanks to *Kevin Cruijssen* for <s>cutting down the import bytes</s> removing the import entirely!

```java
s->b->{String t=s.replaceAll("\\d","2").replaceAll("[a-z]","0").replaceAll("[A-Z]","1").replaceAll("\\D","3"),v="";int a[]={0,0,0,0},i=0,z=0,y=-1>>>1;t.chars().forEach(j->{a[j%4]++;});for(int x:a){z=x>z?x:z;y=x<y?x:y;}for(;i<s.length();i++)v+=a[t.charAt(i)%4]!=(b?z:y)?" ":s.charAt(i);return v;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFPj5swEMXv@RSOtZVsAVbS9tI4Jk3/qYf2tLcStBqIk5h6DcWGBiI@O3VCpKp7qCxLo5@fn2bmFdBCVFbSFPufY67BWvQdlLnMELIOnMpR4RWscUqzQ2Nyp0rDvtyL9aOrlTmG/9V8KEstwYRoEscxOiKBRhvFWRRfJoicsKyWlYZcbrUmeLfb4xC/xvQfmkDUp54vXvJt9OPKly/4bvfJ0zeYhq3AmCvjECSpuCzC2xlCJRZh728nomUcx0vuWH6C2hLKDmX9GfITKXyTkBSv3qZBwAfKPSdXo/MK6KUX57jfnFc978R53fmq48NVwdXaMi3N0Z0I5SoIaBsISCb7rSOKesO5INmmX3V0gxFe2b9vvJauqQ1q@TAixGc@jKrJtA/jnklbqj169jmRaX9Jinw3XoZQNq0bZX7JkCxT5spv5W9ZfwQr/VjyVwPaEuzqRmLKb18eO@vkMysbxyrv5rQhRwZVpTsCySKl9zqjN/0wG8bx6/uH09y8e5o/PPnEN@PBm8o/)

**Explanation:**

```java
String t=s.replaceAll("\\d","2")
          .replaceAll("[a-z]","0")
          .replaceAll("[A-Z]","1")
          .replaceAll("\\D","3")
```

First replaces each group with an integer between 0 and 3 using some simple regex and stores this in a new String.

`int a[]={0,0,0,0},m,i=0,z=0,y=-1>>>1;`

Initialises an array of integers as well as a couple of other integers to use later. Sets the `y` variable to the max int size using unsigned right bit shift.

`t.chars().forEach(j->{a[j%4]++;});`

For each character in the modified string, this uses its ASCII value modulo 4 to calculate the index of the aforementioned array to increment.

```java
for(int x:a){
    z=x>z?x:z;
    y=x<y?x:y;
}
```

This then loops through the counts of each group stored in the array and calculates the minimum (`y`) and the maximum (`z`).

```java
for(;i<s.length();i++)
    v+=a[t.charAt(i)%4]!=(b?z:y)?" ":s.charAt(i);
```

Loops through every character in the String again, checking if the group of that characters group is equal to the min/max (using the modulo trick mentioned earlier). If it isn't equal, then a space is added to the new String in the characters place, otherwise the original character is added.

`return v;`

Finally return the new String!

Comment: Nice answer, +1 from me! Two small things to golf: `import java.util.stream.IntStream;` can be `import java.util.stream.*;` and `,i` can be `,i=0` after which you can remove `i=0` from the for-loop. Oh, and `(s,b)->` can be `s->b->`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks! I didn't realise you could chain lambdas

Comment: It's called currying. :) You can do it like this `java.util.function.Function<String, java.util.function.Function<Boolean, String>> g = s->b->{...};`.

Comment: Oh, and another thing to golf: `IntStream z=IntStream.of(a);m=(b?z.max():z.min()).getAsInt();` can be `l=s.length(),x=0,y=l` and `for(int x:a){z=x>z?x:z;y=x<y?x:y;}` and `(b?z:y)`, so you no longer need the import. Putting it all together becomes: [`s->b->{String t=s.replaceAll("\\d","2").replaceAll("[a-z]","0").replaceAll("[A-Z]","1").replaceAll("\\D","3"),v="";int a[]={0,0,0,0},i=0,l=s.length(),z=0,y=l;t.chars().forEach(j->{a[j%4]++;});for(int x:a){z=x>z?x:z;y=x<y?x:y;}for(;i<l;i++)v+=a[t.charAt(i)%4]!=(b?z:y)?" ":s.charAt(i);return v;}` (**294 bytes**)](https://tinyurl.com/y7dgr2lp).

Comment: Ignore the previous comment (I deleted it), `y` can remain `y=-1>>>1` and the loop can be `for(String p:s.split(""))v+=a[t.charAt(i++)%4]!=(b?z:y)?" ":p;`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Oooooh nice thinking! I might wait a bit before changing it just in case you come up with anything else ;)

Comment: Hehe. :) Well, I'm not at work anymore, so I probably won't look at codegolf until tomorrow. I usually look at codegolf a bit when I have to wait a bit for something at work, but I barely look at it at home.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 139 bytes

```js
s=>b=>s.map(c=>++a[g(c)]&&c,a=[0,0,0,0],g=c=>c>-1?0:/[a-z]/i.test(c)?c<"a"?2:1:3).map(c=>a.map(v=>v-Math[b?"max":"min"](...a))[g(c)]?" ":c)
```

Input and output is an array of characters. Takes actual boolean values for input.

A different approach from [@Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146776/69583); almost avoiding regular expressions. Instead, I used a series of checks to determine the category of each character:

- Digits return `true` for `c>-1` because non-digits fail mathematical comparisons
- Uppercase letters match the regex `/[a-z]/i` and have codepoints less than `"a"`
- Lowercase letters match that regex but have codepoints not less than `"a"`
- Symbols pass none of those tests

### Test Cases

```js
f=
s=>b=>s.map(c=>++a[g(c)]&&c,a=[0,0,0,0],g=c=>c>-1?0:/[a-z]/i.test(c)?c<"a"?2:1:3).map(c=>a.map(v=>v-Math[b?"max":"min"](...a))[g(c)]?" ":c)

;[["Just_A_Test!", true],["Just_A_Test!", false],["Aa1!Bb2@Cc3#Dd4$", true],["Aa1!Bb2@Cc3#Dd4$", false],["H@$h!n9_!$_fun?", true],["H@$h!n9_!$_fun?", false],["A", true],["A", false],["H.ngm.n", true],["H.ngm.n", false],["H.ngm4n", false]]
.forEach(([S,B])=>console.log(`"${S}", ${B} -> "${f(S.split``)(B).join``}"`))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```